# Adding parameter to decorator removes cls parameter

Tags: python, logging, decorator

I want to do logging of MongoEngine Documents in my flask application as described [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html). But I also want to be able to exclude certain attributes that this document class has.

If I give the apply function of a decorator an additional parameter `excludes` the cls parameter is no longer given.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 26, in <module>
    @__log_update.apply(excludes=[])
TypeError: apply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

In the simplified code

```py
def handler(*events):
    """
    Signal decorator to allow use of callback functions as class decorators.
    """
    def decorator(fn):
        def apply(cls, excludes=[]):
            for exclude in excludes:
                print(exclude)

            for event in events:
                event.connect(fn, sender=cls)
            return cls

        fn.apply = apply
        return fn

    return decorator

@handler()
def __log_update(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


@__log_update.apply(excludes=['testString'])
class Test(object):
    testString = ''
    testInt = 0
```

But when just using `@__log_update.apply` without any parameter, the cls parameter is given and is `<class '__main__.Test'>` as it should be.

I need both to do the logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That about how *decorator* works.

When you apply it like so (no matter with or without parameters):

```
@__log_update.apply()
```

the result of invocation should be a *decorator* itself which then applied to the underlying *class*.
You need an additional layer that will make `.apply()` function to return a class decorator:

```
def handler(*events):
    """
    Signal decorator to allow use of callback functions as class decorators.
    """
    def decorator(fn):
        def apply(excludes=[]):
            def class_decor(cls):
                for exclude in excludes:
                    print(exclude)

                for event in events:
                    event.connect(fn, sender=cls)
                return cls
            return class_decor

        fn.apply = apply
        return fn

    return decorator

@handler()
def __log_update(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


@__log_update.apply(excludes=['testString'])
class Test(object):
    testString = ''
    testInt = 0
```